# My login script doesn't properly query the database

Tags: php

Whenever I login with a registered user my script fails with the following message:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\login.php on line 9
>   Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\login.php on line 10
>   Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

The script should query the database to see if the user is valid, but it never comes that far. The actual code is listed below.

connect.php

```
<?php
    mysqli_connect ("localhost","root", "");
    $db = mysqli_select_db("login");
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    require_once('connect.php');
    extract($_POST);

    $result = mysqli_query("select * from users where username = '$username' and password = '$password'");
    $result = mysqli_query( $sql);

    if ( $password == $row['password']) {
        header("location : home.php");
    }
    else {
        echo "failed to login! try again";
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Login page</title>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="frm">
            <form action="login.php" method="POST" style="width: 232px; padding-left: 490px;">
                <h1>Login</h1>

                <p>
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label>password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <input type="submit" id="btn" value="login" style="border-radius: 30%; background-color: gold; box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);"/>
                </p>

                <p>
                    Not yet a member <a href="register.php">Register here</a>
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want help with the code, you need to tell us exactly what is not working, and what you expect to happen. We can't help when you just say "Code not working"

Comment: The problem is that the form is submitting data but it is not inserting into my sql

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. [See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: although the query is working if i use it directly

Comment: just after `<?php` add this :-  `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` and then run your code and see errors.Also where you are executing your query?

Comment: The problem is simple.. you did `not run/execute` the query

Comment: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\connect.php on line 4

Comment: this is the error that is showed

Comment: Update your question with the code from your `connect.php` file.

Comment: <?php

mysqli_connect ("localhost","root", "");
$db = mysqli_select_db("login");

?>

this is the connect .php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is so simple.

You did not execute the query at all.

add `mysqli_query($connectionVar,$sql);` just below `$sql`

> mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

this is what you need.

`mysqli_select_db($connectionVar,"DATABASENAME");`

update:

remove  the select_db function on your con and run this :

```
 $link = mysqli_connect ("localhost","root", "","login");
```

then

`mysqli_query($link,$sql);`

Comment: where  should i add mysqli_query($link,$sql);?

Comment: @IrtazaRawjani below this `$sql = "INSERT INTO `users`(`name`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `contact`) VALUES ('$name','$username','$email','$password','$contact')";`

Comment: cool, don't forget to upvote and mark the answer @IrtazaRawjani

Comment: Please suggest me what to do

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the points that you should use [`PDO`](http://php.net/pdo), [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and generally never using variables directly from user input, there are a few things that needs attention:

connect.php

- `mysqli_connect` can connect directly to the database, no need for `mysqli_select_db`
- you should check if a connection was actually established
- `mysqli_select_db` returns `true` or `false`, so storing that in `$db` only serves to know if the database was successfully selected
- if you actually need a separate database and not just a table for the login, you should select the `login` database from `login.php`
- when there nothing after the closing PHP tag it should be omitted, as this can only lead to confusing and hard-to-track-down bugs

login.php

- `extract` puts everything into variables, potentially overwriting existing variables such as `$db` and `$sql`
- using uppercase for SQL keywords makes the queries much more readable in terms of what is structure and what is names and data
- `$result` is immediately overwritten after the first `mysqli_query` call
- the second `mysqli_query` call runs the query in the undefined variable `$sql` and thus it fails
- comparing `$password` to `$row['password']` will never be true, as you store the query results in the `$result` variable but check the undefined `$row` variable
- after setting the location header on successful login, you might as well stop the script, i.e. by adding `exit(0);`
- on login failure, you should set a variable for use in the HTML output instead of outputting `"failed to login! try again"` in front of the markup for the login page
- there should never be any characters between the closing PHP tag and the start of the HTML output, as this can only lead to confusing and hard-to-track-down bugs

Cleaning the code a bit according to the above will result in something like this:

connect.php

```
<?php
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "login");

    if (!$db) {
        echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
        exit;
    }
```

login.php

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    require_once('connect.php');

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if ($password == $row['password']) {
        header("location: home.php");
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        $feedback = "failed to login! try again";
    }
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Login page</title>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="frm">
            <form action="login.php" method="POST" style="width: 232px; padding-left: 490px;">
                <h1>Login</h1>

                <?php
                    if ($feedback) {
                        echo "<p>" . $feedback . "</p>";
                    }
                ?>

                <p>
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label>password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <input type="submit" id="btn" value="login" style="border-radius: 30%; background-color: gold; box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);"/>
                </p>

                <p>
                    Not yet a member <a href="register.php">Register here</a>
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```